SQL query with grouping of possible values and output blank rows if zero count?
Let say i am department store manager, and i need to count sales from different store A.B C and D.
the code is something like
select   
"Sales" as V1,
count(distinct case when XXX) as V1,
count(distinct case when XXX) as V2,
count(distinct case when XXX) as V3,


from sales_data
group by store;

but in the current sales dataset, there is only data for store A, and B so far and the output above will only have a row for store A and B but not C and D.  how do i make output a blank row for "store" even if it doesnt exist on the dataset, so it alway output for every store?



Department
ID
Sale




A
01
5


A
01
4


B
02
2


A
03
3



so i want output sales by department



Department
Total




A
12


B
2


C
0



i want to perform other query that is grouped by Dept, but i want query output to consider every Dept, even when there is no data like above
thanks
i know this is probably pretty basic, but i tried googling around, and cant find anything

Could you add some simple data and the expected output ? also tag the RDBMS you are using

@SelVazi
Dept, ID, sale
A,01,5
A,01,4
B,02,2
A,03,3
so i want output sales by department
Dept , Total
A,12
B,2
C,0

Which RDBMS (mysql, sql server .. ) you are using ?

Your select statement and output don't match. It seems like you want the department names as column headers, but your output lists them as rows. Could you clarify if you're looking to pivot the rows into columns? Also, which RDBMS are you using?
If you are using SQL Server, check out this example for the pivot query: https://dbfiddle.uk/p5TwaxO0. This script dynamically creates a pivot table to display sales data for each department

The basic solution is that you need a list of all your Departments, regardless of whether they have sales. Ideally this information would be held in a table but you could generate it as part of your query (as @SelVazi has done in their answer) - though this means you would need to alter your query whenever the list of departments changed

Do you have a separate table of Departments?

If you can't presume your data will have a full coverage of departments, you will need a separate data set enumerating the full list.
data departments_all ;
  input department$ @@ ; datalines;
A B C
;
data have ;
input department$ id$ sale ; datalines ;
A   01  5
A   01  4
B   02  2
A   03  3
;
proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select all.department, coalesce(sum(sale),0) as total, count(distinct id) as distinct_id_count
  from departments_all as all
  left join have on all.department = have.department
  group all.department 
  ;



You should use the SUM() function instead of COUNT() :
SELECT t.Department,
       COALESCE(SUM(Sale), 0) as Total
FROM (
  SELECT 'A' AS Department 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'C'
) AS t -- Replace this subquery with the select of all departments
LEFT JOIN sales_data s ON s.Department = t.Department
GROUP BY t.Department

Demo on mysql

The OP didn't specify the source of the departments. The subquery can be replaced with a select of all departments from a table if exists.

I would recommend having a separate dataset that defines all of your expected departments. You can then left join to it. This will ensure that you always have counts for all stores. For example:
/* Pretend this is a permanent dataset or in a database */
data departments;
    input department$;
    datalines;
A
B
C
;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as
        select t1.department
             , CASE(sum(sale))
                   when . then 0  
                   else sum(sale)
               END as total
        from departments as t1
        LEFT JOIN
             have as t2
        ON t1.department = t2.department
        group by t1.department
    ;
quit;

department  total
A           12
B           2
C           0


Yeah that is true, if you swap the datasets for t1 and t2 and left join, you'll get the same answer.
